# How to check if progressDialog is show to user via Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, illegalargumentexception

I'd like to test the behavior of my activity when filePath is null or contains illegal file path.

My activity code is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    filePath = intent.getParcelableExtra(SOMETHING);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) {
        showErrorAndFinishPopup();
        return;
    }
    mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(filePath);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        showErrorAndFinishPopup();
        return;
    }
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("something");
    progressDialog.show();
    ...
}
```

I can make my own intent with 'filePath = null' and start my activity.
However, I am not sure how to check progress dialog is shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a dialog is showing or not by just calling `isShowing` like this:

```
if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                // progressDialog is currently visible
            }
            else
            {
                // progressDialog is currently invisible
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use shadow

```
ShadowProgressDialog.getShownDialogs()
```